# MySQL update query that uses aggregation subquery on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, circular-dependency

I have this table named "TableA" which contains "customer_id" and "name" fields.
I added a new field "ref". Now I want to update that table so that the "ref" field is set to 1001 for the first item of customer_id=1, 1002 for the 2nd item of customer_id=1, etc. and again 1001 for the first item of customer_id=2, etc.

Of course, I've got the that-was-to-be-expected mysql error message "You can't specify target table 'TableA' for update in FROM clause".

Also tried using the (SELECT next_ref FROM (SELECT ... WHERE A_sub.`customer_id` = A.`customer_id`) AS A_sub), but then MySQL says that "A.`customer_id`" isn't found.

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE TableA A
SET A.ref = (
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(A_sub.ref) +1, 1001)
    FROM TableA A_sub
    WHERE A_sub.`customer_id` = A.`customer_id`
)
WHERE o.ref IS NULL;
```

Question is: can this be done in one query or do I have to use a temporary table?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to use `update`/`join`:

```
UPDATE TableA A join
       (SELECT A_sub.`customer_id`, COALESCE(MAX(A_sub.ref) +1, 1001) as newref
        FROM TableA A_sub
        GROUP BY A_sub.`customer_id`
       ) A_Sub
       on A_sub.`customer_id` = A.`customer_id`
  SET A.ref = newref
  WHERE a.ref IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

If you want an auto-incremented id, I would suggest that you define one as such.  If you have to put one in, then you can do:

```
UPDATE TableA A cross join
       (SELECT @rn := coalesce(MAX(A_sub.ref) + 1, 1001) as maxref
        FROM TableA A_sub
       ) vars
  SET A.ref = (@rn := @rn + 1)
  WHERE a.ref IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thx Gordon. The query results in setting "1001" for all the records of TableA, which is not what I expected (tested in MySQL 5.1.72). Is there a way to make MySQL "update" the dataset from the sub select in the join after every update?